# Fourier series question

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

[image]

I am just a beginner in Fourier series.How should I get start to tackle this question and show the partial sum has extrema? I have no clue to this question. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I forgot to upload the function and here it is.

Answer (score 0):

[If square waves are square integrable, why doesn't fourier expanding work?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/698414/if-square-waves-are-square-integrable-why-doesnt-fourier-expanding-work/698775#698775)

The answer on this question is very similar, the overshoot is twice that! I had the same question and someone answered me. Hope this helps